# XML to XSL file

Tags: xml, xslt

i have xml file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<statusfile>
  <job>
      <name>Test2</name>
      <curstatus>SUCCESS</curstatus>
      <stablerevision>5752</stablerevision>
      <curdate>12/02/2015</curdate>
      <prevstatus>FAILURE</prevstatus>
      <prevstable>5745</prevstable>
      <prevdate>12/01/2015</prevdate>
  </job>
  <job>
    <name>Test3</name>
    <curstatus>SUCCESS</curstatus>
    <stablerevision>5752</stablerevision>
    <curdate>12/02/2015</curdate>
    <prevstatus>SUCCESS</prevstatus>
    <prevstable>5745</prevstable>
    <prevdate>12/01/2015</prevdate>
  </job>
</statusfile>
```

this is what i have tried for xsl file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table width="500px" border="1px" style="text-align:left;font-family:consolas">
      <tr bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
        <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
          <b>JOB-NAME</b>
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
          <b>CURRENT-STATUS</b>
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
          <b>REVISION</b>
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
          <b>DATE</b>
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
          <b>PREVIOUS-STATUS</b>
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
          <b>REVISION</b>
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
          <b>DATE</b>
        </td>
      </tr>      
      <xsl:for-each select="statusfile/job">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="curstatus and prevstatus != 'SUCCESS'">
            <xsl:for-each select="statusfile/job/currentstatus">
            <tr bgcolor="#C1E3E8">
              <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
              </td>
              <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                <xsl:value-of select="curstatus"/>
              </td>
              <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                <xsl:value-of select="stablerevision"/>
              </td>
              <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                <xsl:value-of select="curdate"/>
              </td>
              <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                <xsl:value-of select="prevstatus"/>
              </td>
              <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                <xsl:value-of select="prevstable"/>
              </td>
              <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                <xsl:value-of select="prevdate"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:for-each select="statusfile/job/currentstatus">
              <tr bgcolor="#C1E3E8">
                <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                  <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                </td>
                <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                  <xsl:value-of select="curstatus"/>
                </td>
                <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                  <xsl:value-of select="stablerevision"/>
                </td>
                <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                  <xsl:value-of select="curdate"/>
                </td>
                <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                  <xsl:value-of select="prevstatus"/>
                </td>
                <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                  <xsl:value-of select="prevstable"/>
                </td>
                <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                  <xsl:value-of select="prevdate"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>     
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but i am getting only table names, not complete output with job name and its information. Thought something i am missing here

please help me,
advance thanks
Kalyan

Comment: What is the `<xsl:for-each select="statusfile/job/currentstatus">` for? For starters there is no `currentstatus` element in your XML, and if you mean `curstatus` there's only one of them in each `job` anyway.

Comment: Your `<xsl:when test="curstatus and prevstatus != 'SUCCESS'">` will check if the `curstatus` element exists, and that `prevstatus` exists and does not have the value of `'SUCCESS'`, but I suspect that's not what's intended- Are you trying to check if neither element has `'SUCCESS'`?

Answer (score 1):

Several issues here:

- the test "curstatus and prevstatus != 'SUCCESS'" succedes if both of the following are true

  - there exists an element `<curstatus>` below the current node
  - there exists an element `<prevstatus>` below the current node with text-value (contents) different from 'SUCCESS'
- I guess what you are after are the elements where either curstatus or prevstatus are not 'SUCCESS'
- the nested for-each look for elements relative to the current element, which is /statusfile/job, thus it matches only 
  /statusfile/job/statusfile/job/currentstatus, which is probably not what you want
- I would re-write this to use a separate template for the job-element (which is more "xslt-like")

I would write:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table width="500px" border="1px" style="text-align:left;font-family:consolas">
            <tr bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
                <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
                    <b>JOB-NAME</b>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
                    <b>CURRENT-STATUS</b>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
                    <b>REVISION</b>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
                    <b>DATE</b>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
                    <b>PREVIOUS-STATUS</b>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
                    <b>REVISION</b>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
                    <b>DATE</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <apply-templates select="statusfile/job" />
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="job[curstatus != 'SUCCESS' or prevstatus != 'SUCCESS'">
        <tr bgcolor="#C1E3E8">
            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                <xsl:value-of select="curstatus"/>
            </td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                <xsl:value-of select="stablerevision"/>
            </td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                <xsl:value-of select="curdate"/>
            </td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                <xsl:value-of select="prevstatus"/>
            </td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                <xsl:value-of select="prevstable"/>
            </td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                <xsl:value-of select="prevdate"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="job[curstatus = 'SUCCESS' and prevstatus = 'SUCCESS'">
        <tr bgcolor="#C1E3E8">
            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                <xsl:value-of select="curstatus"/>
            </td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                <xsl:value-of select="stablerevision"/>
            </td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                <xsl:value-of select="curdate"/>
            </td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                <xsl:value-of select="prevstatus"/>
            </td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                <xsl:value-of select="prevstable"/>
            </td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                <xsl:value-of select="prevdate"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague, but your main problem is the `<xsl:for-each select="statusfile/job/currentstatus">` - I can't see why it's there, there's no element called `currentstatus` so I can't determine exactly what output you require.

However, try this - I've just removed each `<xsl:for-each select="statusfile/job/currentstatus">` and it at least produces a table row for each `job` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table width="500px" border="1px" style="text-align:left;font-family:consolas">
            <tr bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
                <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
                    <b>JOB-NAME</b>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
                    <b>CURRENT-STATUS</b>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
                    <b>REVISION</b>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
                    <b>DATE</b>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
                    <b>PREVIOUS-STATUS</b>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
                    <b>REVISION</b>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#2EFEF7">
                    <b>DATE</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="statusfile/job">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="curstatus and prevstatus != 'SUCCESS'">
                        <tr bgcolor="#C1E3E8">
                            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                                <xsl:value-of select="curstatus"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                                <xsl:value-of select="stablerevision"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                                <xsl:value-of select="curdate"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                                <xsl:value-of select="prevstatus"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                                <xsl:value-of select="prevstable"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#FF0000">
                                <xsl:value-of select="prevdate"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <tr bgcolor="#C1E3E8">
                            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                                <xsl:value-of select="curstatus"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                                <xsl:value-of select="stablerevision"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                                <xsl:value-of select="curdate"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                                <xsl:value-of select="prevstatus"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                                <xsl:value-of select="prevstable"/>
                            </td>
                            <td style="font-weight:bold" bgcolor="#2EFE2E">
                                <xsl:value-of select="prevdate"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```